# LastFM request on Android

Tags: android, xml, api, key, last.fm

I'm developing a music player on Android.

I would like to use LastFM API.

The problem is when I want to use a method of LastFM.

I sign up and I have an api-key.
If I want to use the method Artist.getSimilar is very easy. 
For example, if I want to search similar artist to 'Cher' using this method, the url is:

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getsimilar&artist=cher&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026

Passing by argument artist and api_key.

The problem is that I want to use the method Artist.getTags

I have to pass forced 4 arguments:

- artist
- api_key
- api_sig
- sk

I have the 2 first arguments, but I can't obtain the api_sig and sk.

I read this document: http://www.lastfm.es/api/authentication

> Construct your api method signatures by first ordering all the
>   parameters sent in your call alphabetically by parameter name and
>   concatenating them into one string using a  scheme. So
>   for a call to auth.getMobileSession you may have:
>
> api_keyxxxxxxxxauthTokenxxxxxxxmethodauth.getMobileSession
>
> Ensure your parameters are utf8 encoded. Now append your secret to
>   this string. Finally, generate an md5 hash of the resulting string.
>   For example, for an account with a secret equal to 'mysecret', your
>   api signature will be:
>
> api signature =
>   md5("api_keyxxxxxxxxauthTokenxxxxxxxmethodauth.getMobileSessionmysecret")
>   Where md5() is an md5 hashing operation and its argument is the string
>   to be hashed. The hashing operation should return a 32-character
>   hexadecimal md5 hash.

But I don't understand anything. First I have to obtain the api_sig, and after obtain the session key, but I haven't idea how do it, which classes use and anything...

Any idea??? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Why reinvent the wheel: there is a last.fm API at http://code.google.com/p/lastfm-java/, and you can see how they create the signature at http://code.google.com/p/lastfm-java/source/browse/trunk/src/de/umass/lastfm/Caller.java (look for the `private Result call(String method, String apiKey, Map<String, String> params, Session session)` method to see how they call the `Authenticator.getSignature` method at http://code.google.com/p/lastfm-java/source/browse/trunk/src/de/umass/lastfm/Authenticator.java).

Answer (score 1):

Try this API:
https://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-android/
I found it [here](http://www.lastfm.ru/group/Last.fm+Android/forum/114391/_/596613). 
It may be useful